# Django Model Loop

Tags: python, database, django, view, models

I am just starting developing with Django, and I'm slowly falling in love. However, i am quite a noob still and have a hard time understanding why this particular model isn't working, so here I am.

I have this model in models.py:

```
class projectBuildTests(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    build = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    testName = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

My view.py goes like this:

```
def home(request):
    projects = projectBuildTests.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('testrunner/home.html')
```

in my home.html I am trying to show it like this:

```
<label>Project:</label><br>
<select class="project_test_selector" multiple="multiple" size="10">
    {% for project in projects %}
    <option>{{ project.text }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I am managing the models data with the django admin. It's registered like this:

```
admin.site.register(projectBuildTests)
```

In the actual admin-panel the model is showing a bit strange. It gives me a bunch of sub-objects instead of a normal column list which I can append data to. I don't know if I'm making sense here :-/

Comment: In your view function, you don't pass the `objects` variable to the template, so it does nothing.

Comment: Also as a style guide - don't use camel-case for python class names `projectBuildTests` should be `ProjectBuildTests`

Comment: I'll fix that, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your views.py, you need to pass `projects` queryset in context of response.

```
from django.template import RequestContext
def home(request):
    extra_context = {}
    projects = projectBuildTests.objects.all()
    extra_context['projects'] = projects
    return render_to_response('testrunner/home.html', extra_context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And in Your Template:

```
<label>Project:</label><br>
<select class="project_test_selector" multiple="multiple" size="10">
    {% for project in projects %}
        <option>{{ project.testName }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: This will throw an error because extra_context isn't defined.

Comment: :D . forget to initialize dictionary . Edited .

Comment: I see. Now it gives me a Nameerror:
global name 'extra_context' is not defined

Comment: You could just use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), then you don't have to fiddle with the request context yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To edit a little Priyank Patel's response..
[Django shorcuts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/) are very useful.
For example, you can import render:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

Then just return:

```
return render(request, 'testrunner/home.html', extra_context)
```

Comment: when would this be more useful than a normal rendertoresponse? Or rather, what's the difference there?

Comment: It's the same thing. 'render' is just a shortcut for render_to_response.